# How to change title using option

Tags: pine-script

In v5 pine editor I want to add language option using input.bool. I want to add English and French options but I couldn't.

Example:

```
lang = input.string(title="Language",
     options=["English", "French"],
     defval="English")
     
langg = (lang == "English") ? EN :
        (lang == "French") ? FR :
        EN
```

I want to use this code for title change. When I choose English, I want the English title, and when I choose French, the French version of the same titles will appear on the settings screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this.

The `title` argument of the `input()` function expects a `const string` which means its value must be known at compile time.

If you are talking about changing the system language, it is not supported.